# Order a subscription on an android app multiple times from the same account

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

I am currently designing a cross platform application for both android and iOS where users can use the same account hosted on my backend for any device using either OS. This means that their data is not connected to their Google Play account or their Apple account. This application will use in-app purchases for subscriptions and consumable products. My question is, if a user a@b.com subscribes using device A, and then another user c@b.com attempts to subscribe using the same device, would the google play store allow the user to make another subscription? Is there a way around it? I've thought about using consumable products and then implementing the subscription logic myself. Do I have any other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Google Play won't allow c@b.com to subscribe.

Whoever downloaded your app will be the owner of your app. If your app starts a subscription purchase flow, then it is at the owner's account. Adding a 2nd account in Google Play won't make it owner to your app and user won't be able to switch account in the purchase flow.

There is no way around it. Even you make your products consumeable, user cannot switch account in the purchase flow. It will be always the owner account which starts the purchase flow.

Comment: Thank you! I'll carry on with the subscription option and users will just have to deal with it.